# Zope Data.fs too large that I can't pack it anymore

Tags: zope

My site's database grew too large that it can't even pack itself anymore. When I do pack it, it says that there's insufficient space.

I've tried deleting some files in the server but to no avail - the database itself just takes the whole disk space.

[image: Zope Control Panel]

How would I continue on from this point? The website is basically stuck since it can't add more data since the disk space is full.

### Additional details

The server is on Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few weeks, I returned to this problem and I have finally fixed it.

It is similar to the idea of @MartijnPieters, but I approached the problem differently.

My zope instance was in `/dev/sda6`, and that filesystem is full. I just increased the size from 27G to 60G and THEN I packed my `Data.fs` file.

I used [GParted](http://www.rootusers.com/use-gparted-to-increase-disk-size-of-a-linux-native-partition/) on my machine but it's because /dev/sda6 is a native linux filesystem. If you're running LVMs, you might need to use [resize2fs](http://www.rootusers.com/how-to-increase-the-size-of-a-linux-lvm-by-expanding-the-virtual-machine-disk/).

Answer (score 1):

Copy the Data.fs file to another machine with more disk space, and pack it there. Then copy the smaller file back to the server, bring that down and move the packed version in place.

Depending on how much downtime you are willing to tolerate, you could remove the large unpacked Data.fs file first, *then* copy the replacement over.

If you are using a blobstorage with your site, you'll have to include that when copying across your ZODB.

Comment: Do I need to move it to another machine with Zope as well, or are there ways to pack it via the command line or without zope?

Comment: @MarkGabriel: you can pack the file with the command line, which means you need to have Zope installed, at least.

Comment: Is this the instruction for the command line packing? http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/persistency/database.html#packing-from-command-line

I'm not exactly sure how this works. I'm not really familiar with Zope as the site I'm currently handling was just passed to me with 0 training given. Sorry about this.

Comment: @MarkGabriel: that command line requires that ZEO is running. That is actually the easiest option; run ZEO with that ZODB (no site needs to run) and then use that command line to trigger the pack. It'll be easier than the next option, where you import all sorts of stuff and tell that to pack. Sorry, it's been a while for me as well and I forgot there is no truly stand-alone command line option to pack.

Comment: I'll try this when I get back to my desk. Thanks a lot